# Query and filter Data Between 2 Dates using datetimepicker c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

I need to filter and query data by using 2 datetimepicker fromdate and todate
when click search button , I tried the following code but its not working :

```
private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string sql = @" SELECT [LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID  as 'Order No.'
   ,labtests.TestId as 'Test Id'
  ,patients.Patient_No as 'Patient File No'
  ,Patients.Patient_Name as 'Patient Name'
  ,testname as 'Test Name'
  ,[RESULT_NUMBER] as 'Result'
  ,Machines.Machine_name as 'Machine'
  ,PatientCat.CatName as 'Category'
  ,departments.dept_name as 'Department'
   ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_BY as 'Examined By'
  ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_DATE as 'Examined Date'
  ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_BY as 'Approved by'
  ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE as 'Approved Date'
  ,[RESULT_REPORT] as 'Report'
  ,[RESULT_NOTE]   as 'Notes'
  ,[NORMAL_RESULT] as 'Normal'
  ,[UPDATED_BY]
  ,[UPDATED_DATE]
  ,REJECTED_BY
  ,REJECTED_DATE
  ,Lab_Reject_Reasons.Reject_Reason

  FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.testid=LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID
  inner join Patients on Patients.Patient_No = Lab_orders_Cash.patient_no
  inner join departments on LAB_RESULTS.deptid = departments.dept_id
  inner join PatientCat on PatientCat.CatId = Lab_orders_Cash.catid
  left join Machines on Machines.Machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id
  left join Lab_Reject_Reasons on (LAB_RESULTS.REJECTED_REASON = Lab_Reject_Reasons.Reject_ID)

  where [LAB_RESULTS].SAMPLE_STATUS in (5,6,8,10)  ";

            string condition = "";
            string orderby = "";
            DateTime fromDate ;
            DateTime toDate ;
            orderby += " order by LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID desc";

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtFromDate.Text, out fromDate))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid From Date");
            }
            else if (!DateTime.TryParse(dtToDate.Text, out toDate))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid to Date");
            }
            else
            {
                condition += " and lab_orders_cash.order_date between '" + fromDate + " and '" + toDate + "'";
            }



            DataTable dt = data.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition + orderby));
            dgvResult.DataSource = dt;
            dgvResult.Refresh();

        }
```

I checked  the questions in this site but no solution .

how to fix my condition to get the data between two dates?

this is the method fireDatatable which read data from the database :

```
public DataTable fireDatatable(string sql)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
                ad.Fill(dt);
                return dt;

            }
            catch
            {
                // error in sql or table 
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                // performance and speed 
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(cn);
                cmd.Dispose();
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's a single quote `'` missing in the condition part of the SQL. Also, you should really parameterise the query

Comment: I have 2 datetimepicker and i found this solution in one site but its not working , i am new to c# , can you recommend the solution i select dates from datetimepicker in sql server when i use select statement with order_date between 2019-12-01 and 2019-12-30 its working and i got data but from the screen its not working with this code ?

Comment: Without seeing your fireDataTable method, it is impossible to be sure, but I am pretty certain you need to format your dates appropriately for your data source. However, you would be far better off using a parameterized query. To help with this, though, we need more information. As a guess try toDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") and the same for fromDate when creating your condition.

Comment: I updated the question and add fireDataTable method

Comment: where to use toDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  ? replace the condition in IF statement or condition ? i will consider to parameterize the query instead. thank you for help :)

Comment: In your condition += eg " between '" + fromDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + ...  Note as @haldo pointed out the added single quote.

Comment: @haldo where is the missing single quote exactly ? thank you

Comment: It is here `'" + fromDate + " and '" `. There should be a single quote before the `and`. 
 It should be `'" + fromDate + "' and '" `

Comment: @haldo Thank you sooo much thats it the error its working now , please add it as solution and i will accept the correct answer , but why its not giving error this missing single quote ?     :::)))

Comment: its not giving error, maybe because in fireDatatable you return null in catch section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from the chat people thank you all , 
you add first the single quote as mr haldo said:

```
else
            {
                condition += " and lab_orders_cash.order_date between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'";
            }
```

then to see the error during runtime remove try and catch from the method as mr Fauzi88 said  :

```
public DataTable fireDatatable(string sql)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) cn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
                ad.Fill(dt);
                return dt;



                // performance and speed 
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(cn);
                cmd.Dispose();
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();

        }
```